# Chrome extension: inserting a javascript tag and calling a function

Tags: javascript, function, google-chrome, background

I have a chrome extension that uses a **content script** in order to dynamically insert a script tag referencing [an external javascript file](http://unixpapa.com/js/dyna1.js). The code I use is:

```
var html_doc = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]; 
var _js = document.createElement('script');  
_js.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript'); 
_js.setAttribute('id', 'chr_js'); 
_js.setAttribute('src', 'http://unixpapa.com/js/dyna1.js'); 
if(!document.getElementById('chr_js')) 
html_doc.appendChild(_js);
```

The external Javascript contains the following code:

```
function lfunc(){
  alert('RUNNING loaded function');
}
alert('LAST LINE of script');
```

When I load a page in a tab the "*LAST LINE of script*" message appears, showing that the script tag is correctly inserted in the DOM.

My extension also has a **button** (i.e., a browser_action). Now, I would like this button to call *lfunc()* defined above whenever it is clicked. Unfortunately, **my code simply doesn't work**.

I use the following code in the *background.html* page to process the onClick event of my button:

```
<script>
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, 
    {code: "try {lfunc()} catch (e) {alert(e);}"});
  }); // it should call lfunc()
</script>
```

The permissions in the *manifest.json* file are:

```
"permissions": [
"tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*"  ]
```

Instead of getting the "*RUNNING loaded function*" message I get the error message "*ReferenceError: lfunc is not defined*".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The external script and content script are completely different (private!) scopes. They can't use eachother's code. They did however invent something for that (sort of): [sendRequest](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/extension.html#method-sendRequest) and [onRequest](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/extension.html#event-onRequest) but **why** are you loading an external script?

Comment: What might work is if you install lfunc into the window's global scope and execute it like that... I'm gonna try that =)

Comment: Well, I can't get it to work. The content script and background page can talk, but it seems they both don't have access to user content in the document's window. (They do have access to the DOM and standard JS, but not to user added functions like your external script).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help Rudie. I would like to load an external script in order to pack most of the functionality of my extension there so that I can reuse it in extensions for other browsers (particularly for IE). By doing so I could also easily update code from the extension by just modifying the external JS file. At least that's the theory :)

Comment: So, is there a way to execute an external JS file from my background page?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can execute the external JS file (by injecting it into the DOM (`document` in the extension)). The external JS file also has access to the local DOM.

Not possible is communciation between those two:

- User-added Javascript (so non-native) can't be accessed by the extension:
  The extension's JS doesn't have access to the page's `jQuery` object, but it does have access to its `document.body`.
- The user-added Javascript (the page's JS or your added external JS) doesn't have access to the extension:
  From the page, you can't access chrome API's, like bookmarks, tabs, browser action etc.

This is done very much intentionally for security reasons.

What I was talking about (`sendRequest` and `onRequest`) is communication between 'content script' and extension script/background pages. In your case irrelevant =) Sorry.

**answers**

> > I cannot call specific functions within the external JS file from the extension because of the lack of communication capabilities between the two

That's right.

> > All I can do is make my extension inject the external JS file into the DOM. This will execute whatever is there to be executed in the external JS file

That's right. The ext JS can contain immediate actions and timers etc, like a normally loaded JS (in the webpage itself) would.

> > The code launching granularity from the extension is at external JS level, not at JS function level

What do you mean by `JS function level`? The extension JS?

**PS**
`chrome.tabs.executeScript` is not quite as cool as you'd think. Basically what it does is execute a script in the page's context (like `content_scripts`). It has, however, the same limits as `content_scripts`: it can reach the DOM and native JS functionality, bot not user added JS. An example:

```
// Inside a `background_page`:
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
    "code": "document.body.removeChild(document.body.firstChild);"
});
```

This works, because only access to the page's (always existing) DOM is required. The following won't work (assuming jQuery was included in the webpage itself):

```
// Still inside a `background_page`:
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
    "code": "jQuery('input').remove();"
});
```

This won't work, because `jQuery` is a foreign, non-native, user-added JS object that's inaccessible to the extension (both `background_page` and `content_scripts`).
I don't really understand the reason for this last limitation, but it's all about sandboxing and security in Chrome =) Which is a good thing I guess...

**BTW**
I think the solution to your problem is quite simple... You can make the `browser_action` inject external JS into the page's DOM. That's enough, right? The external JS contains logic AND the actual function call. Better solution all around, because the external JS is only loaded when the `browser_action` (button) is pushed/triggered. One very slight downside: a very short delay (= downloading the external JS after pushing the `browser_action`).

Might I suggest again: put all your extension JS into the extension. This will allow offline functionality and never require a(nother) connection to a third party server.

Comment: Thanks Rudie! If I understood you correctly, I cannot call specific functions within the external JS file from the extension because of the lack of communication capabilities between the two. All I can do is make my extension inject the external JS file into the DOM. This will execute whatever is there to be executed in the external JS file. The code launching granularity from the extension is at external JS level, not at JS function level. Is that so?

Comment: Answers to your comment in my answer and a little bit about `chrome.tabs.executeScript`

Comment: Thanks for the example and for your advice. Now the problem I'm dealing with is cristal clear to me. I consider the question answered.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `alert('It doesn't work');` with `alert(e);`

This should give you a better idea of what the error is.  Please post the error.

Comment: I inserted the alert(e) and reedited my question with some more info that you may find useful. The error I get is "_ReferenceError: lfunc is not defined_". If I dump the contents of the external Javascript into a file **myContentScript.js** and add it in the _manifest.json_ as a content script, then the whole thing works! But this is **not** good enough for me, since I would like to be able to use an external javascript hosted in a server which does not come in the extension pack... So the question still holds, why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 1):

i needed to invoke a function that was inside one of the pages scripts...

```
location = 'javascript:callToTheFunction(param,param,..)' did it.
```

i'm talking from a content